# Edit array elements

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of drive letters and I need to append a colon to each letter and then pass the array to another function. Can I do this or do I need to create a new array? Or maybe not an array at all but some kind of List instead?

```
string source = "C|D|E";
string[] sourcearray = source.Split('|');
foreach (string driveletter in sourcearray)
{
    //need to append ":" to each drive letter
}
```

EDIT: There are times when the source array could end in a pipe:

```
string source = "C|D|E|";
```

When that happens the last element in the array will be a colon if I use a common for loop, and I can't have this. How best to handle this? When this happens the final array needs to look like:

```
C: D: E:
```

Thanks.

Comment: To the edit: You can tell the Split function to ignore empty values. Check the function overloads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so you can't change the string instance but you must change the array slots with new strings:

```
string source = "C|D|E";
string[] sourcearray = source.Split(new []{'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for(int i=0; i < sourcearray.Length; i++)
{
   sourcearray[i] = sourcearray[i] + ":";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question for a particular case.

Comment: @SixHouse: you can use an overload of Split to skip empty entries, check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your for-loop with

```
 string[] resultArray = sourcearray.Select(s => s + ":").ToArray();
```

Re the Edit:

```
  string source = "C|D|E|";
```

The best solution here is to this is a special variation of the `string.Split()` method. Unfortunately that one requires an array of separator chars, so we get:

```
sourceArray = source.Split(new char[] {'|'}, 
          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: This guy is clearly very new to C#, I'm not sure Lambda Expressions are an appropriate solution...

Comment: @KristianFenn: That's why he needs to be told something about Lambda Expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < sourcearray.Length; i++)
{
   sourceArray[i] += ":";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] sourcearray = source.Split('|').Select(s => s + ":").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = source.Split('|').Select(s => s + ":").ToArray();
```